# Django swagger ui not accessible on nginx

Tags: django, nginx, swagger-ui

I have setup Django using nginx, gunicorn and postgres as per below url.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7

Now I am trying to access swagger ui.

Nginx is up and running however showing default page.

[image]

When I run the same project using,
python manage.py runserver myip:8000
and then access the same url I can see actual swagger ui with rest end points.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Here is what I have added to nginx file.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name <myipaddress>;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /home/threat-dashboard/backend;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/backend.sock;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a mistake in sock file path. I corrected it from /tmp/backend.sock to /tmp/backend/backend.sock and it resolved the issue.